# Incorrect sinc limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I'm trying to compute in *Mathematica* 11.0 the limit of the $\mathrm{sinc}$ function at integers:

```
Assuming[k ∈ Integers, Simplify[Limit[Sin[π x]/(π x), x -> k]]]
```

This gives the result 0, although the limit at $k = 0$ is $1$. What am I missing?

Comment: The result is only *[generically correct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericCases.html)*.

Comment: Either way you'd never get `1`, as `Sin[k \[Pi]]/(k \[Pi])` cannot be simplified to that.

Comment: its not a well posed statement. You can not take a limit of a discrete valued function

Comment: @Feyre The limit is important, which is 1 at 0.

Comment: @george2079 Not sure whether you replied to Feyre or me, but I mean the function as $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @J.M. Can I disable such generically correct solutions, at least selectively?

Comment: well the do this `Assuming[k \[Element] Integers, Simplify[Limit[Sin[Pi*x]/(Pi*x), x -> 0]]]` and you will get the correct result.  This begs a "what are you really trying to do?"

Comment: @george2079 I'm a mathematician trying to shift at least some of my pen-and-paper derivations to Mathematica. I find it difficult that I cannot obtain all solutions by default; non-generic solutions are equally important to me.

Comment: I guess fundamentally you expect `Limit[Sin[Pi*x]/(Pi*x), x -> k]` to give a conditional expression, `Sin[Pi*k]/(Pi*k) for all k!=0, 1 for k==0` ? I don't think there is a simple way to achieve that.

Comment: @george2079 Exactly. Now I have to very careful to study the non-generic cases separately. But this is how it is, and I'll adapt to that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[Sin[Pi*x]/(Pi*x), {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Define the function using [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{Piecewise[{{1, x == 0}}], Element[x, Integers]}}, 
          Sin[Pi*x]/(Pi*x)]
```

[image]

`Piecewise` does not have any options so it cannot make use of the assumption

```
Assuming[Element[x, Integers], f[x]]
```

[image]

However, adding [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) will make use of the assumption

```
Assuming[Element[x, Integers], f[x] // Simplify]
```

[image]

You can use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to simplify the nested `Piecewise` functions to a single `Piecewise` function

```
f[x_] = f[x] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

```
Assuming[Element[x, Integers], f[x] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This includes the nongeneric case in the result:

```
Reduce[k ∈ Integers && L == Limit[Sin[k π]/(k π), x -> k], {L}]
(*  k ∈ Integers && k != 0 && L == Sin[k π]/(k π)  *)
```

Not sure how general the approach is.  It works on this related problem:

```
Reduce[k ∈ Integers && L == Limit[Sin[k π]/(k π (x^2 - 1)), x -> k], {L}]
(*  k ∈ Integers && k (-1 + k^2) != 0 && L == Sin[k π]/((-k + k^3) π)  *)
```

One can extract the cases like this:

```
Solve[Drop[%, -1] /. Unequal -> Equal, k]
(* {{k -> -1}, {k -> 0}, {k -> 1}}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @george2079 said, you can not take the limit of a discrete valued fundtion.

Refering to the answer of @Michael E2, I propose a more general procedure. (Here done for his second example)

First regard k to be real and take the limit

```
Limit[Sin[k \[Pi]]/(k \[Pi] (x^2 - 1)), x -> k]

(*     Sin[k \[Pi]]/(-k \[Pi] + k^3 \[Pi])     *)
```

Then apply Reduce and Simplify, both under the assumption k Element of Integers to get a solution (here a == 0) and a condition, which Integers belong to the solution. The other Integers give indefinite.

```
Assuming[k \[Element] Integers, 
   Simplify[Reduce[Sin[k \[Pi]]/(-k \[Pi] + k^3 \[Pi]) == a, a]]]

(*     k^3 != k && a == 0     *)
```

Solve for the Integer values that give indefinite and you may take the limit at these values

```
sol = k /. Solve[! (k^3 != k), k, Integers]

(*     {-1, 0, 1}     *)

lim = Limit[Sin[k \[Pi]]/(k \[Pi] (k^2 - 1)), k -> #] & /@ sol

(*     {-(1/2), -1, -(1/2)}     *)
```